# Trying to get formset to work with two models in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working. What I want to do is have my inspection_vals formset show inspeciton_val reading and dimension description for each for some reason django keeps yelling at me that description  isn't specified for inspeciton_vals and help would be greatly appreciated. Below I gave more details on what exactly I would like to do :)

Here is my view.py

```
def update_inspection_vals(request, dim_id=None): 
  dims = Dimension.objects.get(pk=dim_id) 
  inspection_inline_formset = inlineformset_factory(Dimension, Inspection_vals, fields=('reading', 'description',)) 
  if request.method == "POST": 
    formset = inspection_inline_formset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=dims) 
    if formset.is_valid(): 
      formset.save() 
      return redirect('inspection_vals') 
  else: 
    formset = inspection_inline_formset(instance=dims) 
  return render(request, 'app/inspection_vals.html', {'formset': formset})
```

models.py (with dimension model and inspection_val model) 
inspeciton_val model has a foreign key dimension which links to my dimension model)

```
class Inspection_vals(models.Model): 
  created_at = models.DateField() 
  updated_at = models.DateField() 
  reading = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
  reading2 = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
  reading3 = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
  reading4 = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
  state = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  state2 = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  state3 = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  state4 = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  approved_by = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  approved_at = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True) 
  dimension = models.ForeignKey(Dimension, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEY) 
  serial_number = models.IntegerField(default=1) 
  #sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_FOREIGN_KEY) 

class Dimension(models.Model): 
  description = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  style = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  created_at = models.DateField() 
  updated_at = models.DateField() 
  target = models.IntegerField() 
  upper_limit = models.IntegerField() 
  lower_limit = models.IntegerField() 
  inspection_tool = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  critical = models.IntegerField() 
  units = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  metric = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  target_strings = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
  ref_dim_id = models.IntegerField() 
  nested_number = models.IntegerField() 

  met_upper = models.IntegerField() 
  met_lower = models.IntegerField() 
  valc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

here is my inspection_vals.html

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %} 
{% block content %} 


<br /> 
<br /> 
<br /> 


<form method="post"> 
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {% for x in formset %} 
      {{ x.as_p }} 
  {% endfor %} 
</form> 






{% endblock %}
```

Screen shot to demonstrate what I would like to see.

[image: What I would like to see]

Comment: Just a hint: shouldn't it be {% for x in formset.forms %}

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the management form in template

```
<form method="post"> 
  {% csrf_token %} 
  {{ formset.management_form }} # important
  {% for x in formset %} 
     {{ x.as_p }} 
  {% endfor %} 
</form>
```